# Beam pipeline deploy to Flink fails with 404

Tags: apache-flink, apache-beam

I'm trying to run a simple Apache Beam pipeline on a [Flink 1.5.2 docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/_/flink/). When I run the main class to deploy the pipeline, I get a weird 404 error. The pipeline runs fine on Google Cloud Dataflow.

I run the main with parameters `--runner=FlinkRunner, --flinkMaster=localhost:8081`, and I can see the Flink dashboard on `http://localhost:8081`. The deploy fails with:

`Unrecognised token 'failure': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null)`

and it appears to have been trying to access `localhost:8081/blobserver/port` based on the debug output - I can confirm this path returns a 404 when I do a get request to it.

I get the a similar problem when I try to deploy the job as a fat jar from the web UI. RestException in JarPlanHandler.

I've tried versions 1.6.0 and 1.5.x - specifically I'm using https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-contrib/docker-flink/docker-compose.yml like this:

`FLINK_DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME=flink:1.5.0 docker-compose up`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Same problem here :) Please let me know if you will find something new.

Comment: Good to know it's not just me - I was starting to question my sanity!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please downgrade your Flink to 1.5.0 and everything should work. In REST API you will find `blobserver/port`

Comment: I should have mentioned, I've tried 1.5.x versions as well as 1.6.0 - so that was the problem for you, older versions didn't fail? I'm using https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-contrib/docker-flink/docker-compose.yml with FLINK_DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME=flink:1.5.0 docker-compose up

Comment: We first tried at Flink 1.5.3, but we found the same problem: missing `blobserver/port` in Flink REST API. Now I can confirm, everything works fine at Flink 1.5.0 + Beam 2.6.0, we are using official Docker image `flink:1.5.0-hadoop27-scala_2.11`

Comment: You are totally right. I must not have tried 1.5.0 specifically. That's a big breaking change that doesn't seem to be documented anywhere obvious!